# How can I write an effective test for game code with a while loop?

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, automated-tests

I have been writing a simple connect four game in python today. I intend for the game to have comprehensive tests.

I have written tests for all of my methods besides the main game loop. I am unsure of how to write an effective test for the main game loop.

In the below function:

- self.move gets the player's move and puts it into the game board; and
- is_game_complete() returns a bool depending on  whether the game is complete.

Both of the above have effective tests.

I am unsure of how to write a useful test for the below. Is a test appropriate?

```
def game_loop(self):
    while True:
        for active_player in self.players:
            self.move(active_player)
            if self.game_checker.is_game_complete():
                return active_player
```

I expect that there is a neat way to write a test, or that a test is unlikely to be useful here.

Thank you very much for any response.

Comment: If you have validated ".is_game_complete()" and "move()", have you not then in essence validated this method (assuming the caller of game_loop doesn't need it or is validated).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't test game loop with unit tests (Too much dependencies to fake). It is not useful here. If you have test for `self.move(active_player)` and `is_game_complete()` that should be enough. You cannot have 100% test coverage especially in game development.

Answer (score 0):

Break your code into testable pieces.

First, a generator that produces a possibly infinite stream of games states, but only on demand:

```
def game_gen(self):
    for active_player in self.players:
        yield self.move(active_player)
```

This requires `self.move` to return something that gets evaluated, rather than simply doing the evaluation itself. This *something* should also keep the active player as an attribute for use later.

Next, write a function that *consumes* a stream of game states:

```
def game_loop(self, stream):
    for move in stream:
        self.evaluate(move)  # Evaluate the move returned by self.move
        if self.game_checker.is_game_complete():
            return move.player  # The player that made the move
```

Now you have two testable pieces. The items yielded by `game_gen` can be tested one at a time, without having to wait for the entire game to be played before the loop terminates. `game_loop` no longer implicitly generates the game; it gets a sequence of moves that is either generated by `game_gen`, or artificial test data that you create yourself to verify that the loop terminates (or doesn't terminate) as necessary.